# TestFlight public link doesn't accept new beta testers

Tags: testflight, testflight-public-link

I created a public link for a group of testers but the link shows: "***This beta isn't accepting any new testers right now.***"

The build has been approved and I set the limit to 10 testers.

[image: TestFlight Beta Group Public Link Options]

Why is the public link not accepting new beta testers?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Well, after writing this, I decided to check the build state and I noticed that the build was missing a step:

[image: TestFlight Beta Group Build Notify Testers]

After notifying the testers, the link now accepts new testers. The link shows: "*To join the Mealcard beta, tap the link on your iPhone or iPad after you install TestFlight.*"

[image: TestFlight Beta Group Build Notified]

Comment: it's also not a bad idea to look at the limitation set for the number of testers

Answer (score 21):

If, like I found, you're finding clicking "Notify Testers" still doesn't work as outlined in Ricardo's post, give it 10 minutes to propagate across Apple's networks.

Comment: omg this is so unclear. I shared enabled link manually and had to use stackoverflow to find this out.... apple sucks in clarity and procedures a lot!

Comment: Its working after clicking "Notify Testers". That's weird!

Comment: In my case, I still see the yellow clock symbol next to "Approved" after 30 minutes. However, refreshing the public link in my browser shows it as live. Do click "Notify Testers", do wait 10-30 minutes, but don't trust the yellow clock!

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case you have to set the run destination to `Any IOS Device (arm64)` and make a new archive file from Xcode. I forgot to change this option in my case. Then you should upload the new archive file to the Apple developer console.

Note: You should update the build number for the new archive file.

Answer (score -3):

If it says that, it may mean that the app you are trying to install dont want anymore poeple 'testing' their app. or it could mean the link has expired